# Matching all occurrences of a html element attribute in notepad++ regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file which has hundreds of links like this:

```
<h3>aspnet</h3>
<a href="http://example.com/1" icon="data:image/png;base64,iwl1zecylifzn3fz9fr3l4cdjqhigcmjo9m">Ex 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/2" icon="data:image/png;base64,ivborw0kggoaaaansuheugaaaqcayaaaaf8">Ex 2</a>
<a href="http://example.com/3" icon="data:image/png;base64,jmiaw+f2pwdohka6t+hnyfanbkwoa1olmug">Ex 3</a>
```

So I want to remove all the elements

`icon="data:image/png;base64,ivborw0kggoaaaansuheugaaabaaaaaqcayaaaaf8..."`

from all the lines. I went through the [official Notepad++ regex wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions) and have come up with this after several trials:

```
icon=\"[^\.]+\"
```

The problem with this is, it is selecting past the second double quote and stopping at the next occurring double quote. To illustrate, this will select the following content:

```
icon="data:image/png;base64,...jbvebich4sec9zgth1sfue1cdt...">EX 1</a> <a href="
```

If I modify the above regex to,

```
icon=\"[^\.]+\">
```

Then it is almost perfect, but it is also selecting the `>`:

```
icon="data:image/png;base64,...jbvebich4sec9zgth1sfue1cdt...">
```

The regex I am looking for would select like this:

```
icon="data:image/png;base64,...jbvebich4sec9zgth1sfue1cdt..."
```

I also tried the following, but it doesn't match anything at all

```
icon=\"[^\.]+\"$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just match anything but a quote, followed by a quote:

```
icon="[^"]+"
```

Just tested with notepad++ 6.2.2 and confirmed that this matches correctly as written.

Broken down:

```
icon="
```

This is fairly obvious, match the literal text `icon="`.

```
[^"]+
```

This means to match any character that is not a `"`.  Adding the `+` after it means "one or more times."

Finally we match another literal `"`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a notepad++ user. so don't know how notepad++ plays with regex, but can you try to replace

`icon=\"[^>]*` to `(empty string)` ?

Comment: That would replace everything past `icon="` — the OP is already replacing too much using their current solution!

Comment: he wants to remove the whole `icon="..."` attribute, doesn't he? `So I want to remove all the elements icon="data:..."` @Barney did u test it? it won't replace "everything" after `icon="` it will do it till the first `>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
This is I just check was working as you wanted it.
The way achieving your goal:

Find what: `(icon.*")|.*?`
Replace with: `$1`

Comment: This will remove approx everything!

Comment: The question mark at end will not allow to remove  ,  I just checked it in my editor

Comment: Sorry replace it with $1 ... I just edited my answer,  I'm extremely sorry